# loading sass using weex and vue gives a "Error: undefined:n1:n2: property missing ':'" for every component

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, sass, weex

Example of the long list of errors I get

```
 error  in ./src/components/ico/icoSandboxThing.vue

(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Error: undefined:4:70: property missing ':',Error: undefined:4:70: missing '}',Error: undefined:4:219: property missing ':',Error: undefined:4:219: missing '}',Error: undefined:11:5: property missing ':',Error: undefined:11:5: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:10: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:10: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:69: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:69: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:218: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:218: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:10: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:10: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:78: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:78: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:227: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:227: missing '}',Error: undefined:20:40: property missing ':',Error: undefined:20:40: missing '}',Error: undefined:21:2: missing '{'

 @ ./src/components/ico/icoSandboxThing.vue 5:20-364
 @ ./.temp/router/index.js
 @ ./.temp/entry.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.188:8081 ./.temp/entry.js

 error  in ./src/components/ico/icoManifestThing.vue

(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Error: undefined:4:70: property missing ':',Error: undefined:4:70: missing '}',Error: undefined:4:219: property missing ':',Error: undefined:4:219: missing '}',Error: undefined:11:5: property missing ':',Error: undefined:11:5: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:10: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:10: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:69: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:69: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:218: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:218: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:10: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:10: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:78: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:78: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:227: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:227: missing '}',Error: undefined:20:40: property missing ':',Error: undefined:20:40: missing '}',Error: undefined:21:2: missing '{'

 @ ./src/components/ico/icoManifestThing.vue 5:20-365
 @ ./.temp/router/index.js
 @ ./.temp/entry.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.188:8081 ./.temp/entry.js

 error  in ./src/components/ico/status.vue

(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Error: undefined:4:70: property missing ':',Error: undefined:4:70: missing '}',Error: undefined:4:219: property missing ':',Error: undefined:4:219: missing '}',Error: undefined:11:5: property missing ':',Error: undefined:11:5: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:10: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:10: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:69: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:69: missing '}',Error: undefined:13:218: property missing ':',Error: undefined:13:218: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:10: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:10: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:78: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:78: missing '}',Error: undefined:14:227: property missing ':',Error: undefined:14:227: missing '}',Error: undefined:20:40: property missing ':',Error: undefined:20:40: missing '}',Error: undefined:21:2: missing '{'

 @ ./src/components/ico/status.vue 5:20-355
 @ ./.temp/router/index.js
 @ ./.temp/entry.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.188:8081 ./.temp/entry.js
```

And here's an example of one the components being included into Vue

https://pastebin.com/ZnXJSz0u

this is my entry.js file

https://pastebin.com/MsBAQ17U

I have got sass-loader and node-sass installed,

to me it looks like it's a babel compilation error or something,

I've gotten some random output in the terminal that looks like this

```
  flex-wrap: wrap\n                position: relative\n                .value-render\n                  // color: $white\n                  color: $friendly\n                  font-size: $littleFont\n                  font-weight: 900\n                  max-height: 100%\n                  width: 100%\n                  max-width: 100%\n                  // text-overflow: ellipsis\n                  // overflow-wrap: wrap\n                  // word-break: break-all\n                  hyphens: auto\n                  white-space: pre-wrap\n                  // overflow: hidden\n                  // text-transform: capitalize\n                  \n          &.title-container\n            >.title-positioner\n              background: rgba($grey, 1)\n              >.title\n              >.type-container\n                width: auto\n                position: absolute\n                top: 10px\n                left: 0\n                padding-left: 16px\n                >.type-positioner\n                  >.type\n                    font-size: $tinyFont\n                    text-transform: capitalize\n                    color: rgba($green, 1)\n          &.description-container\n            // >.option-positioner\n            //   flex-direction: column\n            //   align-items: flex-start\n            //   justify-content: flex-start\n            //   padding: 4px\n            //   >.option\n            //     background: $grey\n            //     width: auto\n            //     padding: 10px 20px\n            //     border-radius: 18px\n            //     border-bottom-left-radius: 5px\n                \n\n          &.icons-container\n            border-radius: 0px\n    &.editing\n      >.main-container\n        background: rgba($grey, 0)\n        >.main-positioner\n          >.option-container\n            >.option-positioner\n              >.value-render-container\n                .value-render-positioner\n                  // background: $white\n                  .value-render\n                    color: $friendly\n            &.title-container\n              >.title-positioner\n                background: rgba($green, .125)\n                border: 1px solid rgba($green, .17)\n                border-bottom: 0px\n              >.type-container\n                >.type-positioner\n                  >.type\n                    color: rgba($friendly, 1)\n            &.description-container\n              // overflow: auto\n              >.description-positioner\n                padding: 5px\n\n                padding-left: 10px\n  &.value\n    &.editing\n      >.main-container\n        >.main-positioner\n          >.option-container\n            &.title-container\n              >.title-positioner\n                background: rgba($green, .125)\n                border: 1px solid rgba($green, .17)\n                border-bottom: 0px\n  &.show-options\n    >.main-container\n      >.main-positioner\n        >.option-container\n          >.option-positioner\n          &.title-container\n            .title-positioner\n              transition: all 250ms, border-radius 0ms\n          &.description-container\n            .description-positioner\n              transition: all 250ms, border-radius 0ms\n          &.inventory-container\n            &.vis\n              &:nth-last(2)\n                padding-bottom: 0px\n\n  &.tight-list-thing\n    margin-bottom: 0px\n    >.main-container\n      >.main-positioner\n        >.option-container\n          >.option-positioner\n            transition: all 300ms ease, border-radius 0ms ease\n    &.editing\n      >.main-container\n        >.main-positioner\n          >.option-container\n            &.value\n              >.value-positioner\n                border-radius: 0px\n    &:not(:last-child)\n      >.main-container\n        >.main-positioner\n          >.option-container\n            >.option-positioner\n              border-radius: 0px\n            &.icons-container\n              >.option-positioner\n                border-radius: 0px\n\n    &:first-child:not(:last-child)\n      >.main-container\n        >.main-positioner\n          >.option-container\n\n          >b:first-of-type\n            &+.option-container\n              >.option-positioner\n                border-radius: 5px 19px 0px 0px\n              &.icons-container\n                border-radius: 0px\n                \n      &.show-options,\n      &.show-value\n        >.main-container\n          >.main-positioner\n            >.option-container\n              &.title-container\n                >.title-positioner\n                  border-radius: 5px 19px 0px 0px\n              &.description-container\n                >.description-positioner\n                  border-radius: 5px 19px 0px 0px\n              &.icons-container\n                >.option-positioner\n                  border-radius: 0px\n\n      &.editing\n        >.main-container\n          >.main-positioner\n            >.option-container\n              >.option-positioner\n                >.option\n                  &.valu
```

So it looks like.. well no actually that's just the sass output hey, I thought that the }'s were being compiled as new lines instead of curly brackets.

any idea what's going on?

My config.js file for weex/webpack
https://pastebin.com/meGFNdet

My utils.js file 
https://pastebin.com/9fmv7tzp

My vue-loader.conf.js file
https://pastebin.com/jZAtw6sk

My webpack.common.conf.js file
https://pastebin.com/AM3Z4EJz

I'm using the 'weex-loader', and postcss is set to false,

I'll do a test with jsfiddle when I get home

can you not flame me for not providing a jsfiddle or enough info, if you don't know the answer from this info, then ask for more info, anyone with experience would know the answer, stack overflow is so dumb in this regard, just help, don't put down or hate, and if you need help in return to help, then ask for it

Answer (score 0):

I have updated some code in webpack.config.js to support .scss and hopes it will help you

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }],
      exclude: /node_modules(?!\/.*(weex).*)/
    }, {
      test: /\.vue(\?[^?]+)?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'weex-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': ['weex-vue-loader/lib/style-loader','sass-loader']
          }
        }
      }]
    }, {
      test: /\.we(\?[^?]+)?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'weex-loader'
      }]
    }]
  }
```

Also have installed `"node-sass"` and `"sass-loader"` dependency

Comment: I've moved onto quasar, I'm really sorry, weex looks awesome because of it's native nature but quasar is a lot further into development at the moment, maybe they can work together in the future, we all hate a waste of time. Thanks so much for your answer <3